# Container the size of screen w/jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to create a  container when a page loads that will be covering the entire screen. If the screen is re-sized the dimensions of the container need to be adjusted accordingly.

I am trying to use jQuery UI draggable and need to user a containment area to prevent dragging outside the visible boundaries of the screen.

```
$("#container").width(window.width());
```

Comment: There is a different between window's viewport size and the screen size.

Comment: Well, which one should I use for draggable elements? I just don't want them to be moved outsize the viewing area, which usually creates a scroll bar in the window, which I try to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind event handlers to window resize: http://api.jquery.com/resize/

```
function resize() {
    $("#container").width($(window).width());
    $("#container").height($(window).height());
}

$(function() {
    //other init code...
    resize();
});

$(window).resize(resize);
```

Though bear in mind using jQuery to resize a part of the page is generally regarded as a bad practice in most cases. Why not CSS?

**edit:** `window` should've been `$(window)` in `resize()`.

Comment: Oh, no, I don't need to resize the window with jQuery. I need the containment to resize when the screen is resized.

Comment: Right. The resize binding does not resize the window. It fires off a function upon window resize.